# Deploying Angular 6 ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I have developed an asp.net core 2.0 MVC application with the addition of an Angular 6 frontend application. They both exist in the same project structure. The asp.net core application acts as an API for the client side Angular 6 application.

I have been developing them side-by-side and included the following code segments inside the Startup.cs file to allow development whilst both applications are running:

```
ConfigureServices
      services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
      });

Configure
      app.UseSpa(spa => {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
          spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
      });
```

The project structure for the Angular application can be found in *ClientApp*.

I know wish to deploy this project to IIS. So I am moving away from a development environment so I know that the line of code: `spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");` is not going to be run.

When I publish the project through Visual Studio and move it to the inetpub folder as I would do for other applications, it does not serve the pages that I have developed within the Angular 6 application. I get 500 internal server error when trying to access a page such as /Home that I have defined within the RoutingModule of the Angular 6 application.

I am presuming that it is because I need to build the Angular application (which I can do through `ng build --prod`) and add the compiled JS files to a HTML page. But I am unsure how to go about this. If anyone has any links to relevant webpages that would be greatly appreciated. Or if you can provide any insight that would be very helpful.

**Update #1:**

Within the Startup.cs file, I made app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() available for when running in production mode.

Instead of a 500 internal server error page, I got exception:
*The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.*

I also noticed that the ClientApp/dist folder was not present after publishing. I manually built ClientApp and added it to the application in inetpub. Now, I get the error in the console:

```
runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

polyfills.7a0e6866a34e280f48e7.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Request:10 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/styles.169e0a841442606822c8.css".

scripts.ee7fed27c36eaa5fa8a9.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

main.befe6f4d3c1275f2e1b3.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Comment: You are writing code of Routing for ASP.NET Core 2.1. For ASP.NET Core 2.0, code is different.

Comment: @WaqasDilawarDaha Do you know what code I need for .Net Core 2.0?

Comment: Let me answer the question.

Comment: Where did you find initial documentation that this was possible/how to do it?  I am working on a similar app and would like to use this workflow for deployment.  However I am using full .net framework, not core.

Comment: @BlackICE I found it here: https://dzone.com/articles/create-an-application-with-angular-6-and-net-core. I also searched for Angular 6 and ASP.NET Core and numerous websites came up.

Comment: This shouldn't be that hard, but you'll need to find the output folder where `index.html` resides, and set your web root folder to that location.

Comment: Also, if an answer was helpful, don't edit the question to say so, please mark it as the answer instead.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm facing the same with ASP.NET Core 2.1 and Angular 7. No suggestions here worked for me. It seems that it always returns index.html, even in scripts and styles requests.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this code for **ASP.NET Core 2.0**, not what you are using. My application is published using this approach.

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
 //Remove this if you don't need it
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
              defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "SPAIndex" }); // For SPA 
        });
```

You need to have a Action in your HomeController which returns a View.
Code for View is

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

Comment: I've removed the app.UseSpa from the Configure method and I have added the core for the view. But the view just returns __Loading...__ back. Within my dist folder I do not have a main-server.

Comment: I did not use the ASP.NET Core Angular template. Rather I created the Angular project separately then wanted to include it in the ASP.NET core application.

Comment: I know, I have done the same, but one thing apart from your question, use ASP.NET Core 2.1. Because ASP.NET Core 2.0 is not Long Term Support candidate.

Comment: Okay, I will update to ASP.NET Core 2.1 to see if this can resolve my issue.

Comment: Be careful while updating, and take time.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1 and this solution don't work either. I think it's more related to angular version than MVC config.

Comment: @Jacobson it is for ASP.NET Core 2.0 and clearly mentioned. And I have mentioned in comment that use ASP.NET Core 2.1 with Angular and don't use ASP.NET Core 2.0. I don't understand the reason of downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Just make this change, it should work for Prod IIS

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist/client";

        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio 2019 brings a project template for this, just select new project in first steps on start page, ASP.NET Core Web Application C#, enter a solution name, and select Angular project template. You may base your solution on ASP.NET Core running under .NET Core or .NET Framework.