# Can't run the Angular application with ASP.NET Core in IIS web server

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis

[image: ClientApp]

Tried to publish an Angular ASP.NET Core application in IIS but it is not working already tried this solution but cannot solve it [Deploying Angular 6 ASP.NET Core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51842620/deploying-angular-6-asp-net-core-application)

Already tried this one.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    ....
    // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist/ClientApp";//change here
    });

     ...
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that your `configuration.RootPath` path is correct? Does the `ClientApp/dist/ClientApp` directory exist in your project's `wwwroot` folder or somewhere else? What happens if you specify an absolute path instead?

Comment: @Dai No it is placed somewhere else. its not inside the wwwroot folder. When i published it. It creates a ClientApp/dist/ClientApp folder

Comment: check this link: https://stackify.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-to-iis/

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this by modifying the `<base href="/">` to `<base href="./">` in index.html